# How to add new timestamp field on logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-4

I'm parsing a log that have previously loaded in my localhost and I would like to get the event date field in each row as a timestamp, but kibana only can gets it as a string.

**Example:**
I have this event

```
2016/09/27 13:33:49.701 GMT(09/27 15:33:49 +0200) INFO       BILLINGGW  ConvergysDelegate.getCustomer(): Calling getCustomerFromCache: 0001:606523
```

It was loaded on **September 27th 2016, 16:04:53.222**, but the logdate field (the event date) is: **2016/09/27 13:33:49.701**.

On logstash filter I defined:

```
(?<logdate>%{NUMBER:year}/%{NUMBER:month}/%{NUMBER:day} %{HOUR:hday}:%{MINUTE:min}:%{SECOND:sec}) %{GREEDYDATA:result}
```

I also proved with:

```
(?<logdate>%{YEAR:year}/%{MONTHNUM:month}/%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hday}:%{MINUTE:min}:%{SECOND:sec}) %{GREEDYDATA:result}
```

And kibana reads logdate like string. How can I get that kibana could read it as timestamp?

I proved only with the date:

```
(?<logdate>%{NUMBER:year}/%{NUMBER:month}/%{NUMBER:day})
```

and Kibana interpreted it properly like timestamp, but the problem is how to add  correctly the hours, minutes and seconds to the logdate field.

Could anyone help me?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert from a string to a timestamp, using the [date filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html).

```
date {
  match => [ "logdate", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"]
}
```

This will attempt to parse the `logdate` field with this date pattern `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` and, if successful, will replace the `@timestamp` field with the result. You can specify another field for the parsed date with the `target` option.

Comment: Thanks @baudsp! It's part of my solution. I needed add some lines more to the data filter: **locale => "ISO8601"** and **target => "mytimestamp"**.